# frequency sampling method) why the coefficient is not symmetric?

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, frequency-response

Here is matlab code
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

```
fs = 2000;    
f = 0:20:1000;    
D = besselj(0,f);    
DD = fliplr(D);    
DD(1) = [];    
DD(end) = [];    
H = [D DD];    
h = ifft(H);
```

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

to make even fir filter

D : half desired frequency response

DD : half desired frequency response

h(1) and h(end) is not symmetric..........

help me

Comment: `h(end)` corresponds to `h(2)`, not to `h(1)`.

Comment: i'am sorry..... Could you speak again?

Comment: Well, it seems you think that `h(1)` and `h(end)` should be identical for the impulse response to be symmetrical. That's not the case.

Comment: because the filter didn't have linear phase right?

Comment: no, generally, that does not have to be the case. If the filter had linear phase, it'd be symmetric.

Comment: please help me lastly, So the filter's impulse response is causal??

Comment: what? I think you're just throwing terms out there that you've heard somewhere...

Comment: i'am sorry... in many case like ideal low pass filter. people around me and paper say that shape filter is non causal. so they delayed this filter. could you explain more? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your impulse response is symmetric. Why do you think it's not?

Symmetry here means

$$h[n] = h[-n]$$

and since a DFT of length $N$ is inherently periodic in both domains with $N$ we can extend this to

$$h[n+kN] = h[-n+mN] \qquad m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Matlab uses unfortunately an array offset of 1, i.e. $h[0]$ is coded as `h(1)` and $h[N-1]$ is `h(N)` or `h(end)`.

Symmetry requires (for example) $h[1] = h[-1]$ which given the periodicity is also $h[1] = h[N-1]$ which in Matlab becomes `h(2) = h(N)`

Comment: but in low pass filter, the h(1) = h(end). in my case what is mean h(1)?

Comment: because of that is not linear phase?